# using delimiter but not delete spaces

Tags: java

I am writing a program where I want to split a string separated by comma. My problem is a user can pass or input the string to the program like this:

```
   Hello,,hey,123
```

So, is there a way that I can add a space between the `hello` and `hey` before I append it to a arraylist. Also my delimiter is ignoring the double `,,` and just going to the next word why is that ?

Comment: How are you breaking the string?

Comment: I am sending it through a scanner than using the delimiter on it

Comment: sorry but that is kind of the opposite solution to what I was looking for. I found my solution by using .trim and than if a string came as "" I just replaced it with " ". Thanks guys for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = "Hello,,hey,123";
String[] tokens = s.split(",", -1);
```

Comment: Only one of the possible solution. Thanks man. But I found my solution already.